Unusual limit in solving electrostatics for point charge above conducting plane
I was trying to solve the following problem without using image charges:
A point charge $q$ is put at distance $d$ above an infinte conducting plane. Determine the induced surface charge density $\sigma$.
Let us consider the total electric field below the plane. Since we are inside a conductor the total field must be zero. Therefore if we calculate the z component of the electric field due to the point charge we get:
$$E_z=\frac{-kq(d-z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(z-d)^2}^3}$$
on the other hand the field due to the induced surface charge is
$$E_{i,z}=-kz\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma (x',y')dx'dy'}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z^2}^3}$$
with a change of variables $u,v=x-x',y-y'$, using polar coordinates after this substitution and using the fact that by symmetry the surface charge can only be a function of r I get the following 1-variable integral:
$$E_{i,z}=-2\pi kz\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma(r)rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}^3}$$
Now my idea: I wanted to consider a point very close to the surface of the plane, that is i wanted to use $E_z+E_{i,z}=0$ in the limit $z\to 0$. So I'd like to evaluate $$lim_{z\to 0}(-2\pi kz\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma(r)rdr}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}^3})$$ If my previous calculations contain no mistake I should get $-2pik\sigma(0)$ from this limit which is equivalent to $-2pik\sigma(x,y)$. Is there a way to evaluate the limit?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The electric field is discontinuous across the surface charge at $z=0$, so you cannot use the fact that $E$ is zero inside the conductor to compute the $E$ outside.

I am confused. How is the space below the plane inside a conductor? The conductor is just the plane, right?

I think you need to calculate the field at a non-conducting $z=0$ plane for a real point charge at $z=d$, and then add a $\sigma(\rho)$ (cylindrical coordinate  rho) so that the field becomes normal at the conductor, and this is mathematically equivalent to adding an image charge, making the effort moot.

With no loss of generality I will let $-k=q=1$ so that in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
E_z(r,z) = \frac{d-z}{\sqrt{r^2+(z-d)^2}^3} \\
E_{i,z}(r,z) = \int\frac{z\sigma(\rho)\rho d\rho d\phi}{\sqrt{r^2+\rho^2+2r\rho\cos\phi+z^2}^3}
$$
First, you need to be careful as a surface charge distribution leads to a discontinuity in $E_z$, so you need to take the limit $z\to0^-$. Second, your integral only valid at $r=0$:
$$
E_{i,z}(0,z) = 2\pi z\int\frac{\sigma(\rho)\rho d\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}^3}
$$
In general, the angular integral is more complicated. Sending $z\to0^-$, you naively get:
$$
E_{i,z}(0,z) \sim 2\pi z\int\frac{\sigma(\rho)d\rho}{\rho^2}
$$
Since you anticipate that $\sigma(0)\neq0$, the integral is infinite but the $z$ prefactor is zero, so you need to be more careful. Actually, it is perhaps simpler to think in cartesian coordinates:
$$
E_{i,z}(0,z) = \int\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}^3}\sigma(x,y)dxdy
$$
From this perspective, it is easier to see that $\delta_z = -\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}^3}$ is a resolution of identity:
$$
\delta_z\to C\delta \quad z\to0^-
$$
with $C$ the positive constant given by:
$$
C = -\int\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}^3}dxdy = 2\pi\int\frac{\rho d\rho}{\sqrt{\rho^2+1}^3}dxdy = 2\pi\left[-(1+\rho^2)^{-1/2}\right]_0^\infty = 2\pi
$$
Indeed, for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, $\delta_z(x,y)\to0$, $\delta_z>0$ and its integral is constant. You therefore get:
$$
E_{i,z}(r=0,0^\pm) = \pm2\pi\sigma(0)
$$
From your shielding condition, you get:
$$
\sigma(0) = -\frac1{2\pi d^2}
$$
You can generalise the previous argument by translation, and get by the shielding condition:
$$
E_{i,z}(r,z\to0^\pm) = \pm2\pi\sigma(r)
$$
You can thus compute the full surface charge distribution:
$$
\sigma(r) = -\frac d{2\pi \sqrt{r^2+d^2}^3}
$$
